# Python BeautifulSoup4 WebCrawler .findAll() not parsing

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, findall

All!

I am attempting to make a python web scraper to pull all the product names from a retail website. The code to do this (in PyCharm) is below:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def louis_spider(max_pages):
    page = 0
    while page <= max_pages:
            url = 'https://us.testcompany.com/eng-us/women/hanbags/_/N-r4xtxc/to-' + str(page)
            source_code = requests.get(url)
            plain_text = source_code.text
            soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, 'html.parser')
            for eachItem in soup.findAll('main', {'class': 'content'}):
               printable = eachItem.get('id')
               print(printable)
               print('Test1')
            page += 1

louis_spider(0)
```

As it currently is (above), the code does not print anything - not even "Test1." I've run this with other inputs in the .findAll()&.get() methods with luck:
`.findAll('a', {'class':'skiplinks'})`and`.get('href')` yielded '#content Test1' and `.findAll('div', {'id':'privateModeMessage'})`and`.get('style')` yielded 'display:none Test1'. Here is a section of the 'inspect element' code from the website, for your reference:

[a snippet of the website's code, providing context for my mentioned attempts which worked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O0vmk.png)

Unfortunately, my code block above, as is, does not yield anything! The problem seems to arise when I try referencing items in the `<main>` section - I get results when referencing the lines up until it. Ideally I would be able to pull the name of each item on the webpage (see this other snapshot of the website's code for a particular reference to what the relevant lines from the website). These lines are within the `<main>` portion of the website's code, so I suspect my for loop is never entered here for the same reason it isn't at any of the other lines within `<main>`, like those in my block above...
[the way I'd write this is .findAll('a', {'class': 'productName'}): and .get('class')](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ErXJk.png)

This being said, I can't find a reason stuff in `<main>` would be inaccessible to BeautifulSoup. Does anyone know why this appears to be happening? Thanks in advance!

Comment: The page is dynamically constructed. You cannot download it with `requests.get`. Consider using `selenium`.

Comment: @DyZ, Thanks for the input! I am working on using Selenium. I can't say your answer has solved my problem because I have yet to get Selenium to work, but you seem to have steered me in the right direction. So requests.get() only works with static webpages/portions of webpages?

Comment: @DyZ my new code (using Selenium): `from selenium import webdriver

chromePath = "/Users/Me/Documents/2018/chromedriver"
browser = webdriver.Chrome(chromePath)

url = 'https://us.louisvuitton.com/eng-us/women/handbags/_/N-r4xtxc/to-0'
browser.get(url)

namesElements = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='productPrice']")

names = []
for x in namesElements:
    print('Test')
    names.append(x.text)
print(names)` only yields an output of "[]". It looks like this is not working any better than my code in the original post. The for loop appears not to be being entered...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the code you posted in the comment, you are getting an empty list because your `XPath` is wrong. The class `productPrice` is inside a `span` tag, not a `div`.

You can get values you want by doing this:

```
namesElements = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[@class='productPrice']")
names = []
[names.append(x.text) for x in namesElements]
print(names)
```